# Как переопределить строку в массив js

Tags: php, javascript

Есть переменная:

```
$line1 = '[385, 231, 175, 121]';
```

Я хочу передать ее в js переменную, чтобы она была как массив. То есть чтобы она обрабатывалась так же как и этот код:

```js
var data1 = [385, 231, 175, 121];
```

Я делаю так:

```js
var data1 = "<?=$line1;?>";
```

Но он не принимает ее как массив.

Comment: потому что для js-кода это по прежнему строка (вы же заключили в двойные кавычки перед тем как вывести переменную).

Comment: Пора уже прочитать про json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php:

```
$line1 = '385, 231, 175, 121';
```

js:

```
var data1 = '<?=$line1;?>'.split(', ');
```

Comment: `'$line1'` это просто строка `$line1`.

Comment: @u_mulder Да, спасибо за поправку.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать это через функцию для работы с JSON, а именно `JSON.parse()`
Вот как будет выглядеть твой пример:

```
$line1 = '[385, 231, 175, 121]';
var data1 = JSON.parse("<?=$line1;?>");
```

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понимаю, у Вас есть PHP `$line1 = '[385, 231, 175, 121]';`

И вы хотите вывести ее в JS-скрипт как массив, вот таким образом - `var data1 = "<?=$line1;?>";`

Но, проблема в том, что JS-скрипт по прежнему восприимает ее как строку (естественно, ведь Вы заключили ее в кавычки).

Как на счет сделать вот так:

```
var data1 = <?= $line1; ?>;
```